# MS SQL . Выборка по периоду

Tags: sql

Есть таблица в которой хранятся данные  с весов. Channel - Date- Value
Каждые полчаса приходят значения. Нужно собрать данные по сумме за смену. Смена начинается с периода 20.00 вчера по 19.50 сегодня. Как написать правильно запрос по  выборке?

`

```
SELECT round(Sum(Mains.Value)/1000,2) FROM [dbo].[Mains] WHERE (ID_Channel=1687)
     and MeasureDate between '2022-31-10 19:50:00.000' and '2022-08-11 20:00:00.000'
GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, MeasureDate), 0)
order BY DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, MeasureDate), 0) asc`
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(hh, 4, [MeasureDate]) AS DATE) AS [Date],
       ROUND(SUM([Value])/1000,2) AS [Value]
FROM [dbo].[Mains] 
-- WHERE ...
GROUP BY [Date]
ORDER BY [Date] ASC
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, заработало!!!